# How can I send general feedback to Sitecore?

Tags: community

As a Sitecore community member, I am looking for ways in which I can provide general feedback to Sitecore. I also have clients who want to do this.

I am aware of Sitecore support tickets and specific areas for providing feedback such as the feedback buttons on knowledge base posts.

I am also aware of more casual ways of providing feedback such as posting in the Sitecore Slack.

Is there an email address that accepts general feedback? What are the most effective methods of submitting general feedback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, I believe product requests should go through the support channels at https://support.sitecore.com/.

There is also a Contact Us page on Sitecore.com where you can fill a form for generic feedback to Sitecore: https://www.sitecore.com/company/contact-us

It also currently lists a phone number to call: +1 855-SITECORE (+1 855-748-3267)

(**NOTE:** As another person has mentioned, this is primarily for sales-related requests, not for technical product questions).

If you are a partner, you also have partner managers that you can connect with to provide feedback. The partner portal is available at https://partners.sitecore.com

If you are a customer, your customer success manager should be able to take in your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The Sitecore Collaborative Program is created to identify in more granular detail today’s Market Problems and related feedback with Sitecore products. By signing up you can make your voice heard and share insights on challenges with the Product & Development Teams. Besides that, you can influence product development roadmap and product design based on participant business needs and market challenges being faced.

*If you work for a customer, please make sure to keep your Customer Success Manager informed.
If you work for a partner, please make sure to keep your Partner Manager informed.*

**The team is happy to take general feedback at CPSupport@sitecore.com**

Answer (score 2):

The above-accepted answer is not valid for technical feedbacks currently as the contact us form seems to be a sales form. Additionally, I haven't received any inputs from Sitecore on whether the email address CPSupport@sitecore.com still tracks active feedback and it seems like it doesn't.

As of 5th June 2023, there isn't a dedicated channel for providing product feedback by Sitecore.

**The only way currently to provide technical feedback is through the Sitecore Slack Chat making use of the respective product channels (like #content-hub, #sxa, etc.)**

I've requested Sitecore to have a dedicated channel for Technical Feedbacks as the current system is not proper.

Attaching a screenshot of the chat on this debated question from Sitecore Slack Chat and the detailed response by Rob Earlam from Sitecore.

[image: Sitecore Slack Chat]

Here is the link of the slack thread for any future references:
https://sitecorechat.slack.com/archives/C09SHRTK2/p1685944342722329

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more specific about the usage of the Contact Us form on sitecore.com. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks Jason, happy that my inputs helped.